# How can I hide specific channels from all members (update)?

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I want to hide a channel from @everyone and later on grant permissions to some specific members, which can then access to the channel.
How can I add that permissions/rules to a channel?

Comment: What channels in which system? There's too little information to go on. Please add more context and details.

Comment: As the tags show it was about discord channels on a server. I found the solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by updating the JDA, which brought some new features:

```
*VOICECHANNEL*.createPermissionOverride(voiceChannel.getGuild().getPublicRole()).setDeny(Permission.VIEW_CHANNEL).queue();
```

- `voiceChannel.getGuild().getPublicRole()` gets the @everyone role
- `.setDeny` can be replaced with `.setAllow`